# CUDA kernel 10x slower when operating on cudaMallocManaged memory even when prefetched

Tags: c++, optimization, cuda, malloc, gpu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};

__global__
void HelloWorld()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}

volatile double dummy = 0;

__global__
void multiply(int N, float* __restrict__ output, const float* __restrict__ x, const float* __restrict__ y)
{
  int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

  for (int i = start; i < N; i += stride) {
    output[i] = x[i] * y[i];
  }
}


int main()
{
  MyTimer timer;
  srand(time(NULL));
  HelloWorld<<<1,1>>>();

  timer.startCounter();
  int N = 2000 * 2000;
  float* h_a = new float[N];
  float* h_b = new float[N];
  float* h_c = new float[N];
  float* h_res = new float[N];
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    h_a[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    h_b[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    h_c[i] = h_a[i] * h_b[i];
  }
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();

  timer.startCounter();
  float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
  cudaMalloc(&d_a, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_b, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, N * sizeof(float));
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "cudaMalloc cost = " << dummy << "\n";

  timer.startCounter();
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "H2D copy cost = " << dummy << "\n";
  
  timer.startCounter();
  constexpr int GRID_DIM = 256;
  constexpr int BLOCK_DIM = 256;
  multiply<<<GRID_DIM, BLOCK_DIM>>>(N, d_c, d_a, d_b);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "kernel cost = " << dummy << "\n";

  timer.startCounter();
  cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_c, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "D2H copy cost = " << timer.getCounterMsPrecise() << "\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (h_res[i] != h_c[i]) {
    cout << "error\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I use normal `cudaMalloc`, the result is

```
Hello world
cudaMalloc cost = 0.599463
H2D copy cost = 5.16785
kernel cost = 0.109068
D2H copy cost = 7.18768
```

but if I use `cudaMallocManaged`, it becomes

```
Hello world
cudaMalloc cost = 0.116722
H2D copy cost = 8.26673
kernel cost = 1.70356
D2H copy cost = 6.8841
```

Why is there such a big performance drop? The code has manually copied the memory to device side, so shouldn't it be exactly the same as regular `cudaMalloc-ed` device memory?

Comment: Please put the code using `cudaMallocManaged` into the question as well. Benchmarking is tricky, therefore I would recommend using a [nvbench](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvbench) instead of creating your own flawed benchmark tooling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using managed memory, "prefetching" does not mean use of `cudaMemcpy`.  I don't recommend use of `cudaMemcpy` with managed memory.  You won't find any training materials that suggest that, and furthermore it will not necessarily do what you think.

To prefetch data in a demand-paged managed memory (also called [unified memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-memory-programming), or UM) regime, you should actually use `cudaMemPrefetchAsync`.  When I do that, I observe no significant difference in performance between the two cases.  For a sensible comparison, I had to refactor your code somewhat:

```
$ cat t2230.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};

__global__
void HelloWorld()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}

volatile double dummy = 0;

__global__
void multiply(int N, float* __restrict__ output, const float* __restrict__ x, const float* __restrict__ y)
{
  int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

  for (int i = start; i < N; i += stride) {
    output[i] = x[i] * y[i];
  }
}


int main()
{
  MyTimer timer;
  srand(time(NULL));
  HelloWorld<<<1,1>>>();
  int N = 2000 * 2000;
  timer.startCounter();
  float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
#ifdef USE_MANAGED
  cudaMallocManaged(&d_a, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&d_b, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&d_c, N * sizeof(float));
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    d_a[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    d_b[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    d_c[i] = 0.f;
  }
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(d_a, N*sizeof(float), 0);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(d_b, N*sizeof(float), 0);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(d_c, N*sizeof(float), 0);
#else
  float* h_a = new float[N];
  float* h_b = new float[N];
  float* h_res = new float[N];
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    h_a[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
    h_b[i] = float(rand() % 1000000) / (rand() % 1000 + 1);
  }
  cudaMalloc(&d_a, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_b, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_c, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
#endif
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "alloc/H2D cost = " << dummy << "\n";
  constexpr int GRID_DIM = 80;
  constexpr int BLOCK_DIM = 1024;

  timer.startCounter();
  multiply<<<GRID_DIM, BLOCK_DIM>>>(N, d_c, d_a, d_b);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "kernel cost = " << dummy << "\n";
  float *res = d_c;
  float *a = d_a;
  float *b = d_b;
#ifndef USE_MANAGED
  timer.startCounter();
  cudaMemcpy(h_res, d_c, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dummy = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
  cout << "D2H copy cost = " << timer.getCounterMsPrecise() << "\n";
  res = h_res;
  a = h_a;
  b = h_b;
#endif

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (res[i] != (a[i]*b[i])) {
    cout << "error\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t2230 t2230.cu
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" ./t2230
Hello world
alloc/H2D cost = 453.012
kernel cost = 0.109507
D2H copy cost = 8.04054
$ nvcc -o t2230 t2230.cu -DUSE_MANAGED
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" ./t2230
Hello world
alloc/H2D cost = 411.502
kernel cost = 0.101654
$
```

(V100, CUDA 11.4)

Note that this assumes you are in a demand-paged UM regime.  If you are not in a demand-paged regime (e.g. on a Maxwell or Kepler device, or on windows, or on Jetson, currently), then you would not use `cudaMemPrefetchAsync`, and the data migration is inextricably linked to the kernel launch.  Also make note of the use of `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`.  In a multi-GPU system, UM can have a variety of different behaviors depending on system topology as well as the GPUs in the system.  This can make an apples-to-apples comparison difficult.

At the end, I did not do prefetching of the data back to the host, if you want compare that activity, you've already been given some [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819026/cuda-unified-memory-how-to-prefetch-from-device-to-host).

Comment: Thanks to your example program, I've found the root problem in this question. It's because I didn't `cudaMemcpy(d_c, ...)`, so `d_c` is untouched before the kernel call. If I add `cudaMemcpy(d_c,...)`, then performance is exactly the same as using UM like in your example.

Comment: But I will follow your guide and not use `cudaMemcpy` with UM. Since it's the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using managed memory, there is an underlying mechanism of exchange between cpu and gpu. Especially when running a kernel for the first time. If you run your kernel several times, the execution time will return to normal.